# DataContractSerializer deserialize repeated property references as null in a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datacontractserializer

Everything was fine, objects were serializing and deserializing just fine with datacontractserializer. However, one of my colleagues created a sample for me that just did not go as it was supposed to. The scenario is like this: we have a list of objects and they consist of properties which are object references and since these are POCO entities created from edmx, there will be circular references for which I have set the PreserveObjectReferences to "true", **but now if two items in the list contain the same property reference only one of them deserializes and the other one will have its property deserialized as null!!!!**

The DataContractSerializer is configured like this:

EDIT: after solving my own problem I only post the simplified version of serialization.

**even in a simplified version I used the same serializer for serialization and deserialization, and same MemoryStream, it is still the same, deserialization does not yield the orignal list :((**

```
returnType = result.GetType().ToString();
serializer = new DataContractSerializer(result.GetType(), null, 0x7fff, false, true, null);
tempStream = new MemoryStream();
serializer.WriteObject(tempStream, result);
tempStream.Position = 0;
serializedReturn = new StreamReader(tempStream).ReadToEnd();
tempStream.Position = 0;
object res = serializer.ReadObject(tempStream);
```

The POCO entities are created by a T4 template by the name of "POCO entity generator" that can be found on the extension online gallery of visual studio. they are not decorated with datacontract and datamember attributes but it worked nonetheless.

I just don't know what might be wrong, because if I do not have repeated references everything is fine, any ideas? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide code of your POCO entities and how you serialize 'em?

Answer (score 1):

OK, since nobody answered or help for that matter, I found the solution myself. The .NET own DataContractSerializer is unfortunately buggy, Instead I used Json.NET from James NewtonKing, kudos to him for making a great serializer which worked for my case while Microsoft's did not.

http://json.codeplex.com/